# The way to upload file on NodeJS server using Ajax

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, vash

Recently I had an issue on how to upload the file to NodeJS server using AJAX, so after many struggles, I finally succeeded to do that.

I posted questions on some developers' spaces to get help, I'd like to share my solutions for others people.

Settings :

- server : Node.JS
- view engine : vash
- uploader module : multer

**, First of all, I install the module **: `npm install multer --save`

**Secondly I set up the APP.JS file: **

...

```
var multer = require('multer');
```

...

```
//Muler manager 
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: 'public/uploads/',
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now()+"-"+file.originalname)
  }
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
app.use(upload.array('files'));
```

**Thirdly the route « index.js »**

```
router.post('/upload', function(req, res, next) {

  //We check the content   
  if(req.files){

    //temporary files array
    var files= [];

    var i = 0,
        len = req.files.length;

    req.files.forEach(function (file, index) {

      i++;

     let file = {
        name : file.filename,
        size : file.size,
        type : file.type,
        path : file.path
      }

      files.push(file);

      if(i == len){ 
          res.send(files);
      }
    })

  }else{
    res.send("Any file uploaded";);
  }

})
```

**Fourthly on the upload.vash (client view)**

```
@html.extend('layout', function(model){
    @html.block('renderbody', function(model){
        <div class="">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <a class="upload-btn">UPLOAD</a>
                    <div class="progress">
                        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar"></div>
                      </div>
                    <input id="fichiers" type="file" name="fichiers" style="display: none" /><br>
                    <ul id="image-list">
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    })
})
```

**Fifthly on the loader.js (client side)**

```
$('.upload-btn').on('click', function () { 


    $('#fichiers').click();

    var input = document.getElementById("fichiers");

    input.addEventListener('change', function(){ 


        var formData = new FormData(),
            file, 
            reader,
            sortie = false; 

        if(input.files.length > 0){

            file = input.files[0]; 
            sortie = true; 
        }

        //And we add the file to  formData object
        //This last will have key "files" And value "the file"
        formData.append('files', file, file.name);  

        //We check the get out condition
        if(true){

            //On exécute la requête ajax
            $.ajax({
                url : '/upload',
                type : 'POST',
                data : formData,
                processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
                contentType: false,  // tell jQuery not to set contentType
                success : function(data) {


                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }

        input.value="";
    })

});
```

** NB: ** The link to loader.js and others files (JS and CSS) are inserted into the ***layout.vash*** file.

---

Regards

Comment: If you've posted a question and want to answer it yourself, you should first post a question and then post your solution as an answer. This makes it easier to search and also follows the normal stack overflow system. You should edit your post to do that if you can!